# How to parse an array in json array

Tags: android

I am parsing json but in my jsonarray I have another array and this arrays values have no tags.(property name.) Here is my code. I can parse the other values but not gallery array. How can I parse gallery array's values in onitemclick method? Thanks.

My json link: http://kilimmobilya.com.tr/mobileservices/default.aspx?i=yeniUrunler

My json:

```
{
    "veri": [
        {
            "id": "1436",
            "tarih": "08.10.2012",
            "baslik": "Ares Plazma TV \u00dcnitesi",
            "kImaj": "http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Plazma-Unitesi/210x120/Ares-Plazma-VS1-00.jpg",
            "kisaAciklama": "",
            "icerik": "",
            "fiyat": "799",
            "Gallery": [
                "http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Plazma-Unitesi/630x360/Ares-Plazma-VS1-00.jpg",
                "http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Plazma-Unitesi/630x360/Ares-Plazma-VS1-01.jpg",
                "http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Plazma-Unitesi/630x360/Ares-Plazma-VS1-02.jpg",
                "http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Plazma-Unitesi/630x360/Ares-Plazma-VS2-00.jpg",
                "http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Plazma-Unitesi/630x360/Ares-Plazma-VS2-01.jpg"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "1434",
            "tarih": "08.10.2012",
            "baslik": "Ares Yatak Odas\u0131",
            "kImaj": "http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Yatak-Odasi/210x120/Ares-Yatak-Odasi-Takim-00.jpg",
            "kisaAciklama": "",
            "icerik": "",
            "fiyat": "5690",
            "Gallery": [
                "http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Yatak-Odasi/630x360/Ares-Yatak-Odasi-Takim-00.jpg",
                "http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Yatak-Odasi/630x360/Ares-Yatak-Odasi-Takim-00-1.jpg",
                "http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Yatak-Odasi/630x360/Ares-Yatak-Odasi-Takim-01.jpg",
                "http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Yatak-Odasi/630x360/Ares-Yatak-Odasi-Takim-02.jpg",
                "http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Yatak-Odasi/630x360/Ares-Yatak-Odasi-Takim-03.jpg",
                "http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Yatak-Odasi/630x360/Ares-Yatak-Odasi-Takim-04.jpg",
                "http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Yatak-Odasi/630x360/Ares-Yatak-Odasi-Takim-05.jpg",
                "http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Yatak-Odasi/630x360/Ares-Yatak-Odasi-Takim-06.jpg",
                "http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Yatak-Odasi/630x360/Ares-Yatak-Odasi-Takim-07.jpg",
                "http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Yatak-Odasi/630x360/Ares-Yatak-Odasi-Takim-08.jpg",
                "http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Yatak-Odasi/630x360/Ares-Yatak-Odasi-Takim-09.jpg",
                "http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Yatak-Odasi/630x360/Ares-Yatak-Odasi-Takim-10.jpg",
                "http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Yatak-Odasi/630x360/Ares-Yatak-Odasi-Takim-11.jpg",
                "http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Yatak-Odasi/630x360/Ares-Yatak-Odasi-Takim-12.jpg",
                "http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Yatak-Odasi/630x360/Ares-Yatak-Odasi-Takim-13.jpg",
                "http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Yatak-Odasi/630x360/Ares-Yatak-Odasi-Takim-14.jpg",
                "http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Yatak-Odasi/630x360/Ares-Yatak-Odasi-Takim-15.jpg",
                "http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Yatak-Odasi/630x360/Ares-Yatak-Odasi-Takim-16.jpg",
                "http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Yatak-Odasi/630x360/Ares-Yatak-Odasi-Takim-17.jpg",
                "http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Yatak-Odasi/630x360/Ares-Yatak-Odasi-Takim-18.jpg",
                "http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Yatak-Odasi/630x360/Ares-Yatak-Odasi-Takim-19.jpg",
                "http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Yatak-Odasi/630x360/Ares-Yatak-Odasi-Takim-20.jpg",
                "http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Yatak-Odasi/630x360/Ares-Yatak-Odasi-Takim-21.jpg",
                "http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Yatak-Odasi/630x360/Ares-Yatak-Odasi-Takim-22.jpg"
            ]
        }
package com.eticaret.hakan;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.eticaret.hakan.R;

import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Yeniurunler extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener,OnClickListener {
    int gelencatid;
    Button altkampanya,altkatalog,altbayi,altiletisim;
    private static final String rssFeed = "http://kilimmobilya.com.tr/mobileservices/default.aspx?i=yeniUrunler";
    private static final String link="http://salih.arti-sanat.com/e-ticaret/s3.jpg";

    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "veri";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_PNAME = "baslik";
    private static final String TAG_PPRICE = "tarih";
    private static final String TAG_PDESCRIPTION = "kisaAciklama";
    private static final String TAG_CREATEDAT = "tarih";

    private static final String TAG_LINK = "kImaj";
    private static final String TAG_GALLERY="Gallery";

    List<Item> arrayOfList;
    ListView listView;
    KampanyaRowAdapter objAdapter;
    JSONArray jsonArray;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.yeniurunler);
        altkampanya=(Button) findViewById(R.id.altkampanyalar);
        altkatalog=(Button) findViewById(R.id.altkataloglar);
        altbayi=(Button) findViewById(R.id.altbayilerimiz);
        altiletisim=(Button) findViewById(R.id.altiletisim);
        altkampanya.setOnClickListener(this);
        altkatalog.setOnClickListener(this);
        altbayi.setOnClickListener(this);
        altiletisim.setOnClickListener(this);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listView.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(0x90000000)); 
        listView.setDividerHeight(1);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        arrayOfList = new ArrayList<Item>();

        if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(Yeniurunler.this)) {
            new MyTask().execute(rssFeed);
        } else {
            showToast("Ağ bağlantısı yok!!!");
        }

    }

    // My AsyncTask start...

    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Yeniurunler.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Yükleniyor...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            return Utils.getJSONString(params[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (null != pDialog && pDialog.isShowing()) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }

            if (null == result || result.length() == 0) {
                showToast("Ürün Bulunamadı");
                Yeniurunler.this.finish();
            } else {

                try {
                    JSONObject mainJson = new JSONObject(result);
                    jsonArray = mainJson.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject objJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        Item objItem = new Item();


                        objItem.setName(objJson.getString(TAG_PNAME));
                        objItem.setCity(objJson.getString(TAG_PDESCRIPTION));
                        objItem.setLink(objJson.getString(TAG_LINK));

                        //objItem.setLink(link);



                        arrayOfList.add(objItem);


                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // check data...

                /*
                 * for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfList.size(); i++) { Item item =
                 * arrayOfList.get(i); System.out.println(item.getId());
                 * 
                 * System.out.println(item.getId());
                 * System.out.println(item.getName());
                 * System.out.println(item.getCity());
                 * System.out.println(item.getGender());
                 * System.out.println(item.getAge());
                 * System.out.println(item.getBirthdate()); }
                 */

                Collections.sort(arrayOfList, new Comparator<Item>() {

                    public int compare(Item lhs, Item rhs) {
                        return (lhs.getAge() - rhs.getAge());
                    }
                });
                setAdapterToListview();

            }

        }
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {


                Intent a = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YeniUrunDetay.class);
                // starting new activity and expecting some response back

                startActivity(a);





        // sending pid to next activity


        }


    public void setAdapterToListview() {
        objAdapter = new KampanyaRowAdapter(Yeniurunler.this, R.layout.kampanyarow,
                arrayOfList);
        listView.setAdapter(objAdapter);
    }

    public void showToast(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(Yeniurunler.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.altkampanyalar:
            Intent goAltkampanya= new Intent(this, Kampanyalar.class);
            startActivity(goAltkampanya);

            break;
        case R.id.altkataloglar:
            Intent goAltkatalog = new Intent(this, Kataloglar.class);
            startActivity(goAltkatalog);

            break;
        case R.id.altbayilerimiz:
            Intent goBAyi= new Intent(this, Bayiler.class);
            startActivity(goBAyi);

            break;
        case R.id.altiletisim:
            Intent goAltiletisim= new Intent(this, Iletisim.class);
            startActivity(goAltiletisim);

            break;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your POJO

```
public class Veri {
    private long id;
    private String date;
    private String baslik;
    private String kImagj;
    private String kisaAciklama;
    private String icerik;
    private String fiyat;
    private List<String> gallery;

    // Constructors, getters and setters…
}
```

Here is the code to parse

```
private List<Veri> parseJson(String json) {
    List<Veri> veriList = new ArrayList<Veri>();

    List<String> galleryImages = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray veriArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("veri");
        int nVeri = veriArray.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < nVeri; i++) {
            JSONObject veriObject = veriArray.getJSONObject(i);
            long id = Long.valueOf(veriObject.getString("id"));
            String date = veriObject.getString("tarih");
            String baslik = veriObject.getString("baslik");
            String kImaj = veriObject.getString("kImaj");
            String kisaAciklama = veriObject.getString("kisaAciklama");
            String icerik = veriObject.getString("icerik");
            String fiyat = veriObject.getString("fiyat");
            JSONArray galleryImageArray = veriObject.getJSONArray("Gallery");

            int nImages = galleryImageArray.length();
            for(int j = 0; j < nImages; i++) {
                galleryImages.add(galleryImageArray.getString(j));
            }

            Veri veri = new Veri();
            veri.setId(id);
            veri.setDate(date);
            veri.setBaslik(baslik);
            veri.setKImagj(kImaj);
            veri.setKisaAciklama(kisaAciklama);
            veri.setFiyat(fiyat);
            veri.setGallery(galleryImages);

            veriList.add(veri);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return veriList;
}
```

This could help!

Comment: do we invoke this function like parseJson("Gallery")  ?

Comment: The String json, parameter is the response that you receive from the URL you have posted.

Comment: I have updated the answer now. You can check the complete example now.

Comment: if we cut these codes  it is working. JSONArray galleryImageArray = veriObject.getJSONArray("Gallery");    
     int nImages = galleryImageArray.length();        
     for(int j = 0; j < nImages; i++) {          
      galleryImages.add(galleryImageArray.getString(j));     
      }

Answer (score 0):

you can use Gson by defining objects accordingly.
for Arrays, naturally there won't be field names, therefore these can be parsed into List.

here comes an example using the response for this url
http://kilimmobilya.com.tr/mobileservices/default.aspx?i=yeniUrunler

JsonObject in the response array is;

```
{
id: "1436",
tarih: "08.10.2012",
baslik: "Ares Plazma TV Ünitesi",
kImaj: "http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Plazma-Unitesi/210x120/Ares-Plazma-VS1-00.jpg",
kisaAciklama: "",
icerik: "",
fiyat: "799",
Gallery: [
"http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Plazma-Unitesi/630x360/Ares-Plazma-VS1-00.jpg",
"http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Plazma-Unitesi/630x360/Ares-Plazma-VS1-01.jpg",
"http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Plazma-Unitesi/630x360/Ares-Plazma-VS1-02.jpg",
"http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Plazma-Unitesi/630x360/Ares-Plazma-VS2-00.jpg",
"http://www.kilimmobilya.com.tr/urunler/PANEL-GRUP/Ares-Plazma-Unitesi/630x360/Ares-Plazma-VS2-01.jpg"
]
},
```

create a Java object as;

```
public class Urun implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Expose public String id;
    @Expose public String tarih;
    @Expose public String baslik;
    @Expose public String kImaj;
    @Expose public String kisaAciklama;
    @Expose public String icerik;
    @Expose public String fiyat;
    @Expose public List<String> Gallery;// notice this is a List of String

}
```

then you can easily parse the JsonObject into defined class. example using Gson

```
Urun urun = (new Gson()).fromJson(jsonObj, Urun.class);
```

hope this helps...